# advantages of webapi in comparison with web services and wcf

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i was asked in an interview the following question about webapi

Why we need webapi?

I told "the services that are created in webapi can be used across wide range of devices like laptop, desktop, tablet and mobiles."

Then the interviewer asked why it cannot be done using web services and wcf?

I don't know the answer.

Can anyone let me know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the title of your question into a search engine yielded the following link.

[WCF and ASP.NET Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx)

> WCF is Microsoft’s unified programming model for building
>   service-oriented applications. It enables developers to build secure,
>   reliable, transacted solutions that integrate across platforms and
>   interoperate with existing investments. (ASP.NET Web API) is a framework
>   that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of
>   clients, including browsers and mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is an
>   ideal platform for building RESTful applications on the .NET
>   Framework.

There is also a table detailing when you should use which.